# Why some React UI library provide Heading, Text, List markup instead h1, p, ul vanilla markup?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, semantic-markup

Why React UI library like [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/), [Mineral UI](https://mineral-ui.netlify.app/) provide

- [`Heading`](https://chakra-ui.com/heading) instead `h1`... vanilla markup?
- [`Text`](https://chakra-ui.com/text) instead `p`... vanilla markup?
- [`List`](https://chakra-ui.com/list), [`ListItem`](https://chakra-ui.com/list) instead `ul`, `li` ... vanilla markup?

I am asking this because I know by heart this vanilla markup and it pains me to learn new markups for this.

On the other hand this React UI library don't handle heading, text and list components: [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/), [Reakit](https://reakit.io/), [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

Answer (score 0):

In short, convenience and flexibility. I'm only familiar with MUI - which by the way **does** handle all of these examples - and it allows you to create a level 4 heading, truncate with a text overflow ellipsis, apply the primary theme color, and horizontally align it like this:

```
<Typography variant="h4" noWrap color="primary" align="center">
  Hello, world!
</Typography>
```

And while this example might still be quickly reproducible without a component library, it would take me not much longer to create a fully responsive, themeable list with nested, collapsable items that have icons, secondary text, action buttons and also cover basic accessability requirements along the way. Doing that from scratch and maintaining it across a large application is not a trivial task.

Last but not least, all this is fully documented, which is **really** important when you collaborate with other developers. Even for seemingly trivial things like creating a level 4 heading.